# How to import image and use in css in sveltekit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm using sveltekit and I'm wondering how to import an image and use it in a CSS background property.
Here's what I've tried:

```html
<script>
    import img from '$lib/images/background-shaded.jpg';
</script>

<div>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>

<style>
    div {
        background-image: url({img});
    }
</style>
```

For now, I'm just putting the image in the the static folder and using via it's URL. Maybe that's the recommended approach...

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't have to import the image at all. Vite will resolve URLs in CSS:

```css
div {
    background-image: url($lib/images/background-shaded.jpg);
}
```

(On build an asset will be emitted and the URL is replaced accordingly.)

Comment: How can I make it work with inline styling?

Comment: @pasta64: Import the image in the script as shown in the question and insert the URL in the `style` attribute. Pretty much what is in the question's CSS, just in the attribute.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was searching for a faster way because I have a big array of images...

Comment: @pasta64: You could maybe use a [glob import](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import) (eager) and loop over the list via `{#each}`.